# [WARN]: Illegal request, responding with status '501 Not Implemented': Unsupported HTTP method: PROXY

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, akka

While starting an ActorSystem, the following warning is getting generated:

```
logMessage="Illegal request, responding with status '501 Not Implemented': Unsupported HTTP method: PROXY", logSource="akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(CustomerService)"
```

Opening AWS ACL for all ports resolve this issue.

How can I stop these warnings?

Edit: the `akka` config is as follows:

```
akka {

  loglevel = INFO
  log-config-on-start = "off"

  http.server {
    idle-timeout = "60 seconds"
    request-timeout = "20 seconds"
    preview.enable-http2 = on
  }
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    debug {
      receive = on
      unhandled = on
    }
  }
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tls-tcp
      canonical.hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      canonical.port = 2552
      bind.hostname = "0.0.0.0"
      bind.port = 2552
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = off

      ssl.config-ssl-engine {
        key-store = "default-keystore.jks"
        trust-store = "default-truststore.jks"
        key-store-password = "default"
        key-password = "default"
        trust-store-password = "default"
        protocol = "TLSv1.2"
        enabled-algorithms = [TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
      }
    }
    watch-failure-detector {
      threshold = 12.0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: without knowing the configuration you have, it's hard to know. maybe this doc about [Unsupported HTTP method: PRI](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.2.3/troubleshooting/unsupported-http-method-pri.html) could help. It has a similar message, but instead of saying `unsupported method PROXY`, it says `unsuported method PRI`

Comment: Added the config used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use a custom http method named `PROXY`. If that is the case, this link https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/954 could help you